# Dart PATH does not change even after changing it in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, flutter, dart, path

I have added the `PATH` in `.bash_profile` like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/ME/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
```

and then have restarted my Mac but then when I do `which flutter dart`, it still show:

```
/Users/ME/development/flutter/bin/flutter
/usr/local/bin/dart
```

According to the article in flutter official site [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path), it is better to have dart at the same folder as Flutter. Excerpt from the article:

> As shown above, the two commands don’t come from the same bin directory. Update your path to use commands from /path-to-flutter-sdk/bin before commands from /usr/local/bin (in this case). After updating your shell for the change to take effect, running the which or where command again should show that the flutter and dart commands now come from the same directory.

Thank you

Comment: what is the value of `PATH` before the line with `export PATH` ?  do you want to prepend ...dart-sdk/bin instead of append?

Comment: This is the `PATH` before that:
`export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"`
`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/ME/development/flutter/bin"`
`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/ME/development/flutter/.pub-cache/bin"`
`export PATH="$PATH:/Users/ME/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"`

Comment: Those are statements that _set_ PATH; we want to know the _value_ of PATH; eg, add a line `echo $PATH` before the original line with `export PATH`; we'll need to confirm where /usr/local/bin appears

Comment: Your problem almost certainly is that `/Users/ME/development/flutter/bin/flutter` and `/usr/local/bin` exist *earlier* in `PATH`.  Order matters; directories listed in `PATH` are searched from left to right, and the first directory that contains the specified command wins.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments.

All I had to do was `brew uninstall dart`

Which will uninstall the one in `/usr/local/bin/dart`

Then after that when I do `which dart` it shows:

`/Users/ME/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart`

Problem solved.

Hope this helps someone who has the same problem.

## UPDATE

I just found it today that I can also change dart path by changing the path in `/etc/paths.d/dart` file. But it needs admin access, so do `sudo nano /etc/paths.d/dart`

Comment: you saved me 